# matplotlib: changing stem plot legend colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

With matplotlib I'm creating stem plots, setting stem plot colors, and creating the plot's legend something like this:

```
import pyplot as plt
...

plots, legend_names = [], []

for x_var in x_vars:
   plots.append(plt.stem(plt.stem(dataframe[y_var], dataframe[x_var]))) 

   markerline, stemlines, baseline = plots[x_var_index]
   plt.setp(stemlines, linewidth=2, color=numpy_rand(3,1))     # set stems to random colors
   plt.setp(markerline, 'markerfacecolor', 'b')                # make points blue 

   legend_names.append(x_var)
...

plt.legend([plot[0] for plot in plots], legend_names, loc='best')
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I'm guessing the first dot in the legend is supposed to correspond to the point color (as it appears in the graph), while the second is supposed to correspond to the stem/line color. However, both stem and point colors end up corresponding to the color of the points in the graph. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default for legend is to display two markers. You can change this with the argument `numpoints = 1`. Your legend command is using the markers, not the lines as inputs by using `plot[0]`. Unfortunately, the stems are not supported artists for legend so you need to use a proxy artist. Here's an example:

```
import pylab as plt
from numpy import random

plots, legend_names = [], []

x1 = [10,20,30]
y1 = [10,20,30]
# some fake data
x2 = [15, 25, 35]
y2 = [15, 25, 35]
x_vars = [x1, x2]
y_vars = [y1, y2]
legend_names = ['a','b']

# create figure
plt.figure()
plt.hold(True)

plots = []
proxies = []


for x_var, y_var in zip(x_vars, y_vars):
    markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(x_var, y_var)
    plots.append((markerline, stemlines, baseline))

    c = color = random.rand(3,1)

    plt.setp(stemlines, linewidth=2, color=c)     # set stems to random colors
    plt.setp(markerline, 'markerfacecolor', 'b')    # make points blue 

    #plot proxy artist
    h, = plt.plot(1,1,color=c)
    proxies.append(h)
# hide proxies    
plt.legend(proxies, legend_names, loc='best', numpoints=1)
for h in proxies:
    h.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]